# Outlet is discolored from my Edenpure heater

Tags: receptacle

My Edenpure heater runs 24/7 in the winter months. The outlet is overheating and the outer plastic is dark brown. I moved it to another outlet and I am plugging the Edenpure in directly, no extension cord. So I tried a multi-plug with a circuit breaker and it burned out.This outlet is now burnt looking too. The Edenpure wasn't running is the only way I discovered it. It probably gave its life protecting my house from a fire. Is there a different outlet I can install that will carry the heavy load of my constantly running heater?

Comment: What's the wattage rating on the heater?  Also, why in the world do you have a space heater running 24/7?

Comment: yes, you can buy 20A outlets, but turn that thing down...

Comment: One case Ive seen this is simply where you have an old home with well-worn outlets. Simply installing a new outlet may do the job. Make sure the prongs on the plug are clean ( light sanding if they look black ).  Also never ever plug/unplug such high power stuff while it is turned on.  Obviously make sure that circuit is protected by a proper size circuit breaker.